# How can I stop Unity 2d intercepting meta key when I'm in VirtualBox?

Tags: 11.10, unity, virtualbox, unity-2d

Whenever I'm working in virtualbox guest system and pressing meta key (aka winkey, or Mod4) a huge unity menu pop ups.

Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to change it, but that is the default for Ubuntu, whether or not in VirtualBox. If you are still able to use it as a modifier (e.g. Super+Whatever), then it is set up correctly, as defined by the powers that be.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems not to be possible - see [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=43911).

Comment: agree with Takkat - if you want to stop the intercepting of the meta key then run the guest in full screen mode - right control + F

Comment: fossfreedom, still intercepting

Comment: @TensaiCirno - very strange - I'm using virtualbox 4.1.6 and running full screen works for me.

Comment: Have you tried auto-capture in VirtualBox?  File >> Preferences >> Input

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to grab the <kbd>Super</kbd> key when working in Virtual Box in non-fullscreen mode as this key is not released by by Unity.

By installation of [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] and running `ccsm` we may define keyboard shortcuts to show unity desktop elements even when Unity2D is running.

> **Warning:** ccsm can lead to unwanted effects that may be hard to overcome and may leave you without a desktop (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/80589/3940) for more background information).

Browse to the *Desktop -> Unity* settings and choose the key shortcut you want to change from the *Behaviour* tab.

**Note:** The Unity plugin does **not** need to be enabled to change keybindings:

[image]

The key that controls the "huge black" dash is the *Key to show the launcher*. By doing so you can assign a different key combination on the host and on the guest to avoid that both open. Note however that still <kbd>Super</kbd> will open the Dash on the host when choosing any combination with the <kbd>Super</kbd>-key (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd>) in the guest.

You can also disable the keyboard shortcut from here.

*This procedure was tested on a virtual machine running 11.10. where we disabled the 3D graphic acceleration in the machine. It may not work the same on real hardware.*

Comment: Are you sure that this settings applied to Unity 2D? Because it isn't compiz plugin, it is standalone QML application. And doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Well, I was only able to test this for Unity2D with compiz **installed** but **not running**. Sorry to hear that it does not work for you.

Comment: Very strange, I'll try with new user profile then. Thanks in advance anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Still doesn't work, even on new profile :/. I created simple patch, to disable unity launcher and turn off highlighting menu on panel when Alt pressed.

[annoying_keys_unity_2d.diff](https://gist.github.com/1352470)

Steps to apply it:

- `cd $build_dir` (any empty dir)
- `apt-get source unity-2d`
- `sudo apt-get build-dep unity-2d`
- `wget https://raw.github.com/gist/1352470/eb9c736bd1041af4be04f0bafdd8e437c222ea15/annoying_keys_unity_2d.diff`
- `patch -Np1 < annoying_keys_unity_2d.diff`
- `cd unity-2d-4.12.0`
- `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b`
- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb`

Answer (score 0):

OK... my question which was related to the Unity 3d dash was closed as it was marked as an "exact" duplicate of this.

Is there a patch to apply this to Unity 3d? Whenever I use the "Alt-L' keys to lock my windows guest, dashboard is brought up in the background and my password is entered in clear text.

Comment: I don't think there is any. But you can write your own patch, just use ````grep```` on sources.