# Virtualbox windows 7 guest - pressing windows key launches unity menu

Tags: virtualbox

Running win7 as guest in full screen mode. When i press windows key or alt+tab the vm looses focus and displays the unity menu or ubuntu's alt+tab.

I've set the VBox configuration: File Menu -> Input -> Auto Capture Keyboard but it looks like some times it captures it and some times it doesn't

Do you know how to run win7 in fullscreen and have all windows key or alt+tab strokes captured by the win7vm only?

Comment: Yes, I have observed exactly the same behaviour, but only for the ALT (=HUD) and Win keys, not the alt-tab strokes. Even in full window mode. I think that it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: switching out of full screen mode using Host-F and then hitting win key results in both the windows start menu and the unity menu launching...

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this issue still seems not to be solved.

Virtual Box may grab all keys from the host OS but Unity seems not to release the <kbd>Super</kbd> and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Therefore our VM will not be able to grab them before the host OS does (see [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=43911)).

As a workaround we may define other keys for opening the Dash and the HUD in the virtual machine and avoid using <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys when working in the VM.

See also:

- [How can I stop Unity 2d intercepting meta key when I'm in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77456/how-can-i-stop-unity-2d-intercepting-meta-key-when-im-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 2):

Upgraded to 12.10 but it wasn't solved :(

I found this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/741869

Go in and mark the bug as "This affects me"

Answer (score 2):

I find that this is sometimes avoidable by pressing and releasing in turn the alt and/or windows keys once inside the guest os with the keyboard captured.

However it's a bit fiddly and doesn't always work!