# Unity and Windows XP guest in VirtualBox conflicts on Meta key

Tags: unity, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtualbox windows 7 guest - pressing windows key launches unity menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191250/virtualbox-windows-7-guest-pressing-windows-key-launches-unity-menu)

When I press the Meta key in the XP guest (to get the start menu), Unity panel pops as well, pretty annoying, is there a way to solve it?